# Wordpress Next & Previous

Tags: wordpress

I am trying extremely hard to show a next & previous button regardless if it is active on my wordpress theme. I cannot seem to figure out a way to make it work. I am trying to do this: http://www.kinocreative.co.uk/hints-and-tips/wordpress-nextprevious-post-navigation-with-images-and-inactive-links/ exactly but for my category archive page. I have tried using something like:

```
<?
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink( get_the_ID()-1 ).'" title="'.get_the_title( get_the_ID()-1 ).'">Previous</a>'; 
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink( get_the_ID()+1 ).'" title="'.get_the_title( get_the_ID()-1 ).'">Next</a>';
?>
```

But that doesn't work to go to the next/previous page of categories.

Comment: Does this help? http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links

Comment: Not really I've read that about 100 times and I cant figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

While this may not be the case for you, I have found through the different themes I've implemented, that not all pages support the next and previous buttons being added. There is a certain way the posts are requested from the database that doesn't always give you what you want.

If you have followed the guides out there (like I did), it's possible that page in particular just won't support it. I know it's not the answer you're looking for, but take it into concideration instead of wasting all your time. You could always edit the theme entirely to allow a feature like this. Take a look at editing how your theme is generating posts altogether, instead of just trying to add the buttons.

These may be handy:

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: Good start. Please complete your answer and provide links to any relevant guides that are useful references here.

Comment: Must have been a formatting tag. I didn't check the contents, but that's happened to me before. Always hard to learn the syntax.